# draw image from isolated storage in xna?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xna, isolatedstorage

How to read and draw image from isolated storage in xna???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but anyways, you would need actually implement System.IO.IsolatedStorage.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

Read up on that, and try to use Texture2D instead of a BitMap image.
I know you can make a new Texture2D from Microsoft's Content Pipeline, but the Texture2D constructors are weird.

You can also try making a Silverlight and XNA Project and see what it does when you have a BitMap within the GraphicsDevice.

I am sorry I am making you try these things cause I am away from my computer right now.
Very unusual request :P

Best of luck,
Robert.